# Using a classifier column to filter dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I think this should be asked before, but with the keywords I couldn't find an answer to this simple question.

I have a dataframe df, and a classifier output clf. I would like the output to be the nth element of the row, as specified by the nth element the classifier, for all rows of the dataframe. so the output is basically [df.iloc[0,1], df.iloc[1,0], df.iloc[2,2], where [1,0,2] is clf, the classifier

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'zero':[1,2,3], 'one':[4,5,6], 'two':[7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
clf = [1,0,2]
output = [4,2,9]
```

Thanks for any help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy solution with indexing by `range` and `clf` is:

```
output = df.to_numpy()[range(len(df)), clf].tolist()
print (output)
[4, 2, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
print([df.iloc[i, j] for i, j in enumerate(clf)])
```

---

```
[4, 2, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use np.diagonal

```
np.diagonal(df.iloc[:,clf])
```

output:

```
array([4, 2, 9])
```